# AWS ALB - proper handling Client Login Timeout when using Keycloak IDP

Tags: oauth, keycloak, aws-application-load-balancer

we have a web app deployed in AWS ECS behind Application Load Balancer. We have configured the Application Load Balancer to securely authenticate users as they access our applications and as the IDP we use Keycloak.

There is a limitation in AWS ALB - citing from the official documentation:

> Client login timeout
>
> A client must initiate and complete the authentication process within 15 minutes. If a client fails to complete authentication within the 15-minute limit, it receives an HTTP 401 error from the load balancer. This timeout can't be changed or removed.
>
> For example, if a user loads the login page through the Application Load Balancer, they must complete the login process within 15 minutes. If the user waits and then attempts to log in after the 15-minute timeout has expired, the load balancer returns an HTTP 401 error. The user will have to refresh the page and attempt logging in again.

The problem is that when my user enters the secure page, he/she is redirected to the Keycloak IDP login page. Everything works smoothly except the case when the user remains at the login page for more than 15 minutes. Then, as stated in the documentation, we get the 401 (login timeout) when redirecting back to the redirect_uri. But the AWS 401 page is just simple html page without link to the original application and the look and feel of the page is not customisable.

It is not possible to somehow modify the look and feel of the 401 page returned by AWS (at least I didn't find a way how to modify it) so the only solution I can imagine is to somehow handle this at the KC site.

Do anyone know if there any (simple) solution for this ?

I tried to set the login timeout on the KC site does not work because it will not redirect user back to the app page (behind ALB) where new "state" token would be generated but it just refreshes the IDP login page (so the state token on AWS ALB is not regenerated).